# Android is not working on Windows 7

Tags: android, windows-7, sdk

I am novice in android development and facing some problems. I have installed Eclipse helios along with ADT 0.9.9 and Android Windows SDK and android 2.2 package. I have developed a small app for testing (one button and EditText control which displays message when user clicks button), it complied successfully. But when I want to run this on emulator its not showing there. It once installed and worked but after I updated my code (Updated only message which will be displayed when user clicks button) its not showing the updated output so I uninstalled app from emulator using app manager. I tried every thing **(used Run As and creating Android config even freshly installed SDK**) to solve the problem but couldn't. Even DDMS not listing any process or any sign of running emulator. Not in even Log Cat

Comment: RAJK we need a log posting form you to help..both the main eclipse log(your eclipse install folder) and any Eclipse Android plugin logcat log that showed up..

Comment: That's probably not the cause of your problem but just so you know The [Eclipse plugin page](http://developer.android.com/sdk/eclipse-adt.html) contains the following warning: *"Caution: There are known issues with the ADT plugin running with Eclipse 3.6. Please stay on 3.5 until further notice."* And you are using Eclipse Helios which is 3.6

Comment: I changed eclipse to Galileo but same problem, I even tried ADT 0.9.6 but problem persists.

Comment: Are you able to connect to the emulator at all? Does `adb shell` works?

Comment: I can query adb from cmd, do u want me to run specific command then just tell me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. In bin folder of application project you will find the .apk file. Manually install it on emulator or device
2. Check manifest file to see which activity is first loaded?

I prefer 2.